# How to replace nullable object in list model?

Tags: c#, .net

There is a strange bug in source code where it instance a new class that randomly become `null`.  The bad part is the null object get assigned to the list model.  So, I'm trying to replace null object with error object with no luck.

I get this error message

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection` when trying to replace null object.

So, how do you fix this?

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool ErrorFlag { get; set; }
}

//Sample to produce the bug...
var modelFoos = new List<Foo>();
modelFoos.Add(new Foo() { ErrorFlag = false; } );
modelFoos.Add(new Foo() { ErrorFlag = false; } );
modelFoos.Add(null);  //This happen when strange bug occurred
modelFoos.Add(new Foo() { ErrorFlag = false; } );
modelFoos.Add(new Foo() { ErrorFlag = false; } );

for(var x = 0; x < modelFoos.Count; x++)
{
    if (modelFoos[x] == null)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { ErrorFlag = true; };
        modelFoos[x] = foo;  //This is where I get exception error
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted works fine, as expected (after removing the invalid semicolons). Can you provide a minimal code sample that actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: I think that you have problem with concurrent threads that use modelFoos. If you add your code in a sample project you will see that it runs without error. The only way to get this error is if someone modify the array before you access it.

Comment: Yea, code is fine. Error message suggest's that you are trying to access element of array that array doesn't have for example if you would use `<=` instead of `<` in the loop

Comment: It's a large script that is run in parallel tasks but this script is inside a class or scope.  I don't see how.   Just that when using the `new Foo() {}` become null by itself which makes no sense.  My more immediate concern is to replace the null object for now.  The example I posted above is the short version that I can make do with.

Comment: "It's a large script that is run in parallel tasks" well, you haven't said that in the question.

Comment: That 'parallel' part is important - you should definitely mention that in your question. Without seeing your actual code I'd guess that multiple threads have access to that list, and one is removing items while another tries to replace them. You'll need to guard against that - don't allow other threads to access that collection while you're modifying it. A read-write lock could be useful here, or perhaps there's a specific thread-safe collection that's suitable for your particular use-case.

Comment: The parallel tasks was completed and it returned the list model into another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code runs in parallel tasks, just use [lock Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to prevent 
this problem.

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical
>   section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If
>   another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block,
>   until the object is released.

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();

lock (thisLock)
{
   foreach(var x = 0; x < modelFoos.Count; x++)
   {
    if (modelFoos[x] == null)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { ErrorFlag = true; };
        modelFoos[x] = foo;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is new to me.   Testing it for 5 minutes now, so far so good.  That works pretty well now.  I can see the speed difference now, it now pause for a moment then resume.  Nice!

Comment: That will keep other threads from accessing the same code - whatever is inside the lock. It will not protect the list or items in the list from being modified by other threads.

Answer (score 4):

Two things suggest to me that there's multithreading going on here, and another thread is modifying this list while you're operating on it.

First is this:

> randomly become null

If it appears random and the code you're working on isn't changing it, then perhaps it's getting changed in another thread.

But here's the bigger flag:

```
if (modelFoos[x] == null)
{
    var foo = new Foo() { ErrorFlag = true; };
    modelFoos[x] = foo;  //This is where I get exception error
}
```

The index isn't out of range when you're checking for null, but it is out of range a few lines later. That means that the number of items in the list has changed between those two lines of code, and not *by* that code.

Those two signs seem to indicate that something on another thread is making changes to the same collection.

It might help if you provide a more complete code sample. It looks like you tried to simplify it to post it here, but the relevant details might be missing. Is that list getting passed into the method from somewhere else or is it actually being created in this method? My guess is it's getting passed in, so there are other references to that same list that something else is modifying.

Comment: Just saw your last message - it's run in parallel tasks. That fits my guess. See if one of those parallel tasks is setting references to null or modifying that list.

Comment: But this null fixing script is run after parallel tasks was done and list model get returned.

Comment: If there's one parallel task going on, could there be another? Also, how are you executing the parallel tasks? It's possible that they are getting executed first but this next part is getting executed before those are finished.

Comment: Just as a sanity check - don't leave this in your code - call System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) before your null fix and see if the problem persists. That's not the easiest way to debug but it's something I can recommend without being able to see the rest of the code.

Comment: We have been warned to never use the sleep command because it can unexpectly cause issues.    The other guy who posted this answer said to use lock statement.  I never heard of lock so I tried it out and it works great.  I can see the parallel tasks pause for a moment then resume.  Wow.  But thanks for your posted answer.   I thought there was a bug when trying to fix the null object but it didn't make sense to me that parallel had somethign to do with it becuase it was done and it returned the value already.

Comment: I would never use sleep either for any reason other than testing. That was just a quick and dirty debug check to see if some previously started process was still running.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`for(var x = 0; x < modelFoos.Count; x++)`
instead of `for(var x = 0; x <= modelFoos.Count; x++)`

You are going too far in that loop.

Comment: That <= wasn't in there when it was first posted. I think someone suggested it and the post was edited. But it was right the first time, < not <-=.

Comment: Thats why I said the 'code is fine' at first, but author change it constantly :/

Comment: Yea, I did.   The other guy confused me until I realized that guy was in error.